# PHP function called on link click not giving any results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to solve this for some time. I have PHP function that is called on link click. When I click on link it's directing me to this function but it's not giving any results.

Here is how I call function.

```
foreach ($bandsN as $aa) {
                $str = explode(',', $aa);
                $next = $str[1];               
                ?>    
                <a href="?other"> <?php echo $str[0]?>  </a></div> <?php  
                if (isset($_GET['other'])) {other($next);}
               }
```

In this function it's called mysql stored procedure with parameter of php function.

```
function other($var)
                {                   
                    echo $var;
                    if (!$mysqli->multi_query("CALL p($var)")) {
                    echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
                }
                do{    
                   if($resul = $mysqli->store_result()){       
                        $bands = array();
                   while($ro = $resul->fetch_row())
                   {     
                    $bands[] = implode(',', $ro);
                   }  
                   foreach ($bands as $aa) { ?>
                    <p > <?php echo $aa?>  </p> </div><?php
                   }
                   $resul->free();
                   unset($bands);
                   }}
                while($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
                }
```

I don't know which is the problem. This code inside function is working because I already have it in other part of app. 
If somebody can see what is wrong I would be very grateful.

Comment: How are you calling it ?

Comment: I added in question